# Apache WicketStuff REST get list of request headers

Tags: java, wicket, wicketstuff

I am using apache wicket stuff REST, and in a simple API... I would like to get the list of headers and simply display it as debug log.

My problem is I am getting an error `java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException`

From Code:

```
@MethodMapping(value="/testSubmit", httpMethod=HttpMethod.POST)
public Object testSubmit() {
    return "OK";
}
```

To Code:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;

...

@MethodMapping(value="/testSubmit", httpMethod=HttpMethod.POST)
public Object testSubmit(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
    // Display request headers here
    return "OK";
}
```

I think the problem is `@RequestHeader`, `HttpHeaders` which are from springframework.
If I can get the wicketstuff equivalent for these... I will not get the error.

Any idea on how I could fix these or the wicketstuff equivalent for getting the list of request headers?

Thanks

Comment: you can get headers public Object testSubmit(@RequestHeader("Accept-Encoding") String encoding) {
    // Display request headers here
    return "OK";
}

Comment: I need all the headers in the request, I was able to get it thru `HttpServletRequest` then `getHeaderNames()` to get the list of header names.. and iterate this names to get the header values.

Answer (score 0):

Since I only need to display the list of headers in the request, I used `HttpServletRequest` then call `getHeaderNames()` to get the header names.

Iterate then the header names to get the header values.

To get the HttpServletRequest in wicketstuff rest, in my case I called it like:
`HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) getCurrentWebRequest().getContainerRequest();`

*Note:*
`getCurrentWebRequest()` is from `org.wicketstuff.rest.resource.AbstractRestResource`, and `getContainerRequest()` is from `org.apache.wicket.request.Request.getContainerRequest()`

```
public static String getHeaderInfo(HttpServletRequest request) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("\n");
    sb.append("\n[HTTP request headers]\n");

    Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();

        sb.append("\"");
        sb.append(headerName);
        sb.append("\": \"");

        Enumeration<String> headers = request.getHeaders(headerName);
        while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerValue = headers.nextElement();
            sb.append(headerValue);
            if (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
        }

        sb.append("\"\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

So, to display the header info:
`System.out.println(getHeaderInfo(request));`

Which is just what I need, I just need this to reflect in my debug log

Hope this helps